# Three.js change visibility of multiple objects with dat.gui.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to put multiple stl files on one page and be able to turn off the visibility individual objects to be able to better view the objects that are still there.  I am using Three.js and trying to use dat.gui.js.  Please help me with how I can achieve this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
function init() {

    var stats = initStats();

    // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    // create a render and set the size
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE, 1.0));
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            var doublebitt = new THREE.Object3D();
            loader.load("models/006858_binary.stl", function (geometry) {
                console.log(geometry);
                var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x789000});
                doublebitt = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
                doublebitt.rotation.x = 0 * Math.PI;
                doublebitt.scale.set(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
                scene.add(doublebitt);
            });

    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            var main_356 = new THREE.Object3D();
            loader.load("models/356/356_side.stl", function (geometry) {
                console.log(geometry);
                var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x789000});
                main_356 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
                main_356.rotation.x = 0 * Math.PI;
                main_356.scale.set(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
                scene.add(main_356);
            });

    // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
    camera.position.x = -30;
    camera.position.y = 40;
    camera.position.z = 30;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(00, 0, 0));

    var orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    orbit.autoRotate = true;
    var clock = new THREE.Clock();

    // add subtle ambient lighting
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    // add spotlight for the shadows
    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(-40, 60, 020);
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(spotLight);

    // add the output of the renderer to the html element
    document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // call the render function
    var step = 0;

    var controls = new function () {

        this.visible = true;

    };


    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(controls, 'visible');

    render();

    function render() {
        stats.update();

        // render using requestAnimationFrame


        doublebitt.visible = controls.visible;
        main_356.visible = controls.visible;

        var delta = clock.getDelta();
        orbit.update(delta);

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    function initStats() {

        var stats = new Stats();

        stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

        // Align top-left
        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
        stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

        document.getElementById("Stats-output").appendChild(stats.domElement);

        return stats;
    }
}
window.onload = init
```

Comment: if all your objects are inside the stl file you cannot do what you are asking as the stl file keeps no hierarchy of its data.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best way, but I found a way to make this work.  If you add a control for each object then it works.
var controls = new function () {
            this.visible = true;
        };
  
  var controls2 = new function () {
            this.visible = true;
        };
gui.add(controls, 'visible');
gui.add(controls, 'visible');
main_body.visible = controls.visible;
main_side.visible = controls2.visible;